# CSS Vertical Menu with submenu callouts overlapping

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Its been a while - but I found myself a new exiting hobby in web development, and I am hoping that you can help me overcome the following issue:

I am working on a personal website. Content etc. is all preliminary. My main focus is the vertical menu on the left hand side. While I am pretty happy with the appearance so far, there are still some questions:

1) I had to set the transition as ease out to >0s, so that I have enough time between the main-menu hover and the hover over the sub-menu. Because of this, if I hover between main-menu items, they will briefly overlap due to the phase out. Is there a way to work around this?
(the focus selector might be an option, but that requires to click the menu item, and I prefer the hover)

2) The sub-menu is aligned to the top of the li of the main-menu. Because of that, the last item's sub (Testing) exceeds the boundaries of the page, giving whitespace below the page. Is there a way to make the sub-menu shift up if it presses against the edge of the overall body?
I probably could give it a different tag and design it differently, am I am hoping there is a more general solution.

3) Minor issue: When switching from main-menu hover to sub-menu hover, the main-icon "blinks" very briefly. Is that normal behavior? Certainly isn't pretty.

4) Last but not least: As this is my first time doing a website, I would be more than grateful to get your general feedback on inefficiencies in the code, so I can be more lean in the future.

(see updated fiddle below - full code removed to save space.)

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT**
THanks for your answers - issue #1 has been solved using the approaches you outlined!

However, the last submenu still gives me a bit a headache.

If I use the "last-child" selector, and the code added below, it will not change anything. However, if I give the last "bubble" a different tag, using the exact same code, the bubble will align to the bottom of the last main-menu item, but the containing UL remains defiant.

As you can see from the original CSS, the last "relative" is the main-menu IL, so shouldn't the submenu and the containing UL both align to the bottom of their respective parent/grandparent?

- using a dedicated, different tag for the last-child "bubble_last
  [image: using a dedicated, different tag for the last-child "bubble_last"]
- Using the last-child selector
  [image: Using the last-child selector]

and the accompanying new code (updated fiddle with full code: Heres the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chimpsociety/895asawg/2/) ...use large screen for the result to see the alignment issue):

```
.navigation ul li:last-child {
    border: solid orange;
}

.navigation .bubble_last{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0%;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 60px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid red;
}

.navigation .bubble_last ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: : 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: solid blue;
    margin-left: 28%;
    display: block;

}

.navigation .bubble_last ul li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 2vw;
    line-height: 1.2vw;
    width: 20vw;
    position: relative; 
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a transition delay on `.bubble`, you just need to make the `.bubble` class wide enough (and start behind the main `li` trigger with a `left: 60px`) so that the hover will be continuous:

```
.navigation .bubble {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0%;
  padding: 0px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: none;
}
```

Then just add a `margin-left` to the submenu:

```
.navigation ul li ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

To fix your second issue, simply add the following CSS to make the last submenu positioned relative to the bottom of the nav item:

```
ul li ul.subm:last-child {
  top: auto;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Updated Demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xbjjbqpz/1/)

Comment: Seems easy and elegant enough!

Do you have any leads on the 2nd question, the issue regarding the overextending last sub-menu as seen on the bottom of the page? Is there a solution, or do I have style this one individually?

Comment: @chimp I have updated my answer above with a solution for the 2nd question.  [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xbjjbqpz/1/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried using your approach, but while the bubble div aligns nicely to the bottom of the last main-menu item, the contained UL remaisn stubborn. I have updated the original issue to reflect the issue including screenshots. Would be great if you could review and let me know which is the brick wall that I keep banging into.

Comment: @chimp Sure, how about this? [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/895asawg/5/) You just needed to fix your `bottom: 0` (had a typo) and add some `top: auto` declarations to override the defaults.

Comment: Holy smokes - this morning I went through almost all the lines, altering and deleting to see if something would change...and all because of this small extra colon. 

Ah well, thank you for solving this issue! 
After learning the application of the last-child selector through trial and error, my front page now performs as I drew it up in my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @chimp No problem! Glad you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Adjust your navigation to use the `nav` element, set it to use flex box, adjust that so it fits the height of your page, and then adjust the transition effects so they transition in and out properly.

I hope this helps.

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
* {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.landing {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://imageshack.com/i/poXkyeIYj") 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.landing .welcome {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 89%;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 30%;
}

#mug {
  background: url("https://imageshack.com/i/pmJaAuFkj") 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 3px #FFF;
  /*max-width: 20%;
    max-height: 20%; */
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav img {
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 100px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 11vw;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-color: none;
}

nav ul li {
  background-color: rgba(222, 225, 229, 0.8);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.nav ul:before,
.nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #595959;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(242, 93, 38, 0.8);
}

.nav li ul {
  background: #273754;
}

.nav li ul li {
  width: 200px;
}

.nav li ul a {
  border: none;
}

.nav li ul a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11vw;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: 200ms ease;
  transition: 200ms ease;
}

.nav ul>li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

span.caption {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="landing">
    <div class="welcome">
      <div id="mug">
      </div>

      <h1>Welcome to my personal Website!</h1>
      <h2>On this site you will find a information about the person, the profession and other stuff about me. Enjoy!</h2>

    </div>





    <!-- cleaned up the navigation, nested it within the rest of the page, and adjusted the css -->
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://google.de" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/potj2pVwp"> <span class="caption">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/pntQ9nVMp"><span class="caption">About Me</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">What I do</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Motorcycling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/po4WFq6Yp"><span class="caption">Professional</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Current Employment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Working Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/pmcfm7Kbp"> <span class="caption">Projects</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/pnM0Fmgrp"> <span class="caption">Misc</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/poqRnk6ap"> <span class="caption">Testing</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="item"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/pmc8tts9p"> <span class="caption">Contact</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be an interesting approach!

MAy I ask what the benefit of the nav tag is? w3schools only lists that browsers may skip rendering, but doesn t go any deeper. 

Lastly, do you have any idea how to approach the 2nd issue - the fact that the last submenu overextends the page?

Comment: Semantic tag usage is great for SEO, for starters. It also makes for a better user experience when everything is organized and logical.

HTML5 just has a smoother approach. While there are still some browsers that don't support some tags in HTML5, it's still a better choice to implement it site-wide. ---------

The last sub-menu overextends the page because its options extend past the page. You could set the sub-menu to `bottom: 0`, rather than `top: 0`. -------- 

I'll post some links for further reading.

Comment: Further reading: Dzone: 10 Major Benefits [link](https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-major-benefits-of-html-5) 
Hubpages 5 Benefits [link](https://hubpages.com/technology/HTML5-is-Here-Now-HTML5-Benefits-for-Users-and-Developers)  
GoMoLearning Why HTML5 Is Important [link](https://www.gomolearning.com/blog/what-is-html5-why-is-it-important/) 
Comlabindia 6 Benefits of Developing Content in HTML5 [link](http://blog.commlabindia.com/elearning-development/6-benefits-of-developing-content-in-html5-infographic)

Comment: Erm, still tired, let me try again: Further reading: [Dzone: 10 Major Benefits](https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-major-benefits-of-html-5)  ---- 
 [Hubpages 5 Benefits](https://hubpages.com/technology/HTML5-is-Here-Now-HTML5-Benefits-for-Users-and-Developers)   ---- 
 [GoMoLearning Why HTML5 Is Important](https://www.gomolearning.com/blog/what-is-html5-why-is-it-important/) ---- 
 [Comlabindia 6 Benefits of Developing Content in HTML5](http://blog.commlabindia.com/elearning-development/6-benefits-of-developing-content-in-html5-infographic) ----

Comment: Thansk for providing the reading materials - thats super helpful! 

So the last sub-menu still is a headache. The absolute position-bottom: 0 will not work for the life of me. I will update the original issue with updated code. WOuld be great if you could take a look!